# are some proprietary driver options hidden - my graphics card isn't listed

Tags: drivers

This is my graphics card

```
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics] (rev e2)
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Stoney [Radeon R2/R3/R4/R5 Graphics]
        Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
        Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

I seem to remember having a proprietary driver option on this screen:

[image]

I think I might have had two wifi options before, and two graphics options, but I'm not sure because the computer worked well enough for a couple years.

Did open source alternatives get developed and cause the free as in beer options to get removed since then?  Is there as way to ask ubuntu to find the drivers for me like it did before?

When I try to search for my graphics card here I can't make sense of it:
https://www.amd.com/en/support

Comment: The actual problem if anybody is wondering is that both screens work until I log in, and then the built in laptop screen goes black even though it is still part of the screen layout (so I can navigate my pointer into the black area, and sometimes the menus are in there so I can't do anything).  I have got it working a bit better by putting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="radeon.modeset=0"` into my grub config

Comment: There is no prop. driver for AMD; a couple of years ago AMD cancelled the driver. AMD cards are 100% supported through linux itself. So no... no hidden 3rd party drivers

Comment: So what would happen if I installed windows? Or they support it for windows but not linux?

Comment: I seem to have solved my problem with `radeon.modeset=1` - but I don't know if that was from changing linux kernels a few times as well, or updating something else while fiddling, or removing `quiet splash` without setting modeset to 0.  I am mainly writing this here so I find it next time I search the internet for the exact same problem, but maybe it'll help somebody else!

Comment: it was suggested in a comment here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/307885

Comment: If anybody else is having this issue, the "solution" was going back to linux kernel version 5.4.173-1 because 5.10.93-1 and 5.16.2-1 both had issues with the built in screen and sleep.  The problem is that those new kernels had fixed the wifi, so I had to install https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce to get my realtek wifi card working